# typo3 powermail hidden informations after 6.2 to 7.6 migration

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

i would like to know why some informations from forms disappears from back-office:

For each form,

```
Mail to receiver
Mail to user
Submit page
```

are empty but in front, after form submition, these infos are displayed.
So they exists but i can't edit it.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you tried the default templates? Are you using default template for mails, defined in the plugin?

Comment: It's all the plugin that crashes.

On page "test", i have "form 1" form.

In plugin, options, i choose another form, "form 2".

After saving, i see that "form 1" is chosen, not "form 2"